# How to dynamically add items to list box inside Modal Popup  in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `Listbox` which I add items to it in the `OnClick` event. I have this `Listbox` inside a panel(`Pnl_Pdfviewers`) and `table`.

This panel is the pop up panel which is make it visible in the `onclick` event

```
  Onclickevent
   {
       //Call method to fill list box
       ModalPopupExtender2.Show();
   }


    // Fill list box
    reader = server.ExecuteReader(CommandType.Text, usernameQuery, paramete);
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        lst_PdfViewers.Items.Add(reader["Name"].ToString());
    }
    reader.Close();
```

everything is fine, but the `listbox` is always empty. I read the value from the `table` and add that to the `listbox`. Why is the `listbox` empty always?

```
<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender2" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"                 TargetControlID="btnShowPopup2"  CancelControlID="btn_PdfCancel"  PopupControlID="Pnl_Pdfviewers" runat="server"> </asp:ModalPopupExtender>
  <asp:Panel ID="Pnl_Pdfviewers" runat="server" BackColor="White" Height="250px" Width="350px" Style="display: none">
     <table>
        <tr>
          <td align="center">
             <asp:ListBox ID="lst_PdfViewers"   runat="server" ></asp:ListBox>
           </td>
         </tr>
     </table> 
  </asp:Panel>
```

UPDATE:

```
 DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds = server.ExecuteQuery(CommandType.Text, usernameQuery, paramete);
           lst_PdfViewers.DataSource = ds;
           lst_PdfViewers.DataBind();
```

Databinding is done successfully but it is not displaying inside the modal pop up extender

Comment: Should I do databinding or how can I do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ll suggest wrapping your `Listbox` with an `UpdatePanel` and calling  `myUpdatePanel.Update();` after

```
lst_PdfViewers.DataBind();
```

It works for us in similar cases. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, I wrapped it with update panel but still wasnt getting it. I had to click a button to get the name. Now using myUpdatePanel.Update(); it works. Thanks a lot